Data is not added to the database
I use the Room library to work with the database
Problem: I created a second table to store songs that can be added to my playlist, before that I had 1 table in the database that stored the user's songs, after adding the second table everything broke, I can't insert songs into my second table (and into the first one now too)
The idea is to add several tracks to the second table, and then draw them in the list using the adapter, and then add tracks to the user's main playlist
ERROR:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.musicapplication, PID: 7521
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity.
I would be grateful for any help!

fragment
package com.example.musicapplication.Fragments

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
import androidx.lifecycle.asLiveData
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.musicapplication.AddSongAdapter
import com.example.musicapplication.DataBase.SongDb
import com.example.musicapplication.DataBase.SongInstance
import com.example.musicapplication.R
import com.example.musicapplication.SongActivity.SongActivity
import com.example.musicapplication.SongAdapter
import com.example.musicapplication.databinding.FragmentTemplateBinding

class BrowseFragment : Fragment(), SongAdapter.Listener, AddSongAdapter.Listener {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTemplateBinding
    private val addSongAdapter = AddSongAdapter(this)
    private var songList = ArrayList<SongInstance>()

    private var songs = arrayListOf(
        SongInstance(0, R.drawable.song, "First song", "First author", R.raw.fairytale),
        SongInstance(1, R.drawable.song, "Second song", "Second author", R.raw.arcade),
        SongInstance(2, R.drawable.song, "Third song", "Third author", R.raw.come_alive),
        SongInstance(3, R.drawable.song, "Fourth song", "Fourth author", R.raw.my_type),
        SongInstance(4, R.drawable.song, "Fifth song", "Fifth author", R.raw.heat_waves)
    )

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentTemplateBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        init()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun init() {
        fragmentData()
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = BrowseFragment()
    }

    private fun fragmentData() {
        binding.apply {
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
            recyclerView.adapter = addSongAdapter
        }

        val db = SongDb.getDb(requireContext())
        for (song in songs) {
            db.getDao().insertSongInBrowse(song)
        }

        db.getDao().getAllSongInBrowse().asLiveData().observe(requireActivity()) {
            addSongAdapter.addSongs(it as ArrayList<SongInstance>)
        }
    }
}

entities.kt
package com.example.musicapplication.DataBase

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity (tableName = "songs")
data class SongInstance(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image") val image: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author") val author: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "song") val song: Int
)

@Entity(tableName = "addSongs")
data class AddSongInstance(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "image") val image: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title") val title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "author") val author: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "song") val song: Int
)


addSongAdapter.kt
package com.example.musicapplication

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.musicapplication.DataBase.SongDb
import com.example.musicapplication.DataBase.SongInstance
import com.example.musicapplication.databinding.AddSongInstanceBinding

class AddSongAdapter(private val listener: Listener): RecyclerView.Adapter<AddSongAdapter.SongHolder>() {
    private var songList = ArrayList<SongInstance>()

    class SongHolder(item: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(item) {
        private val binding = AddSongInstanceBinding.bind(item)
        fun bind(song: SongInstance, listener: Listener) = with(binding) {
            songLogo.setImageResource(song.image)
            songTitle.text = song.title
            songAuthor.text = song.author

            addSongButton.setOnClickListener {
                listener.addSong(song)
            }

            holder.setOnClickListener {
                listener.showSong(song)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SongHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.add_song_instance, parent, false)
        return SongHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return songList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SongHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(songList[position], listener)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun addSongs(songs: ArrayList<SongInstance>) {
        songList.clear()
        songList = songs
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun removeSong(song: SongInstance) {
        songList.remove(song)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun editSongList(filteredList: ArrayList<SongInstance>) {
        songList = filteredList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    fun clear() {
        songList.clear()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    interface Listener {
        fun addSong(song: SongInstance) {}
        fun showSong(song: SongInstance) {}
    }

}

songDb.kt
package com.example.musicapplication.DataBase

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.musicapplication.DataBase.SongInstance

@Database (entities = [SongInstance::class, AddSongInstance::class], version = 2, exportSchema = false)
abstract class SongDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getDao(): Dao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: SongDb? = null

        fun getDb(context: Context): SongDb {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance !== null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    SongDb::class.java,
                    "database.db"
                ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}

Dao.kt
package com.example.musicapplication.DataBase

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
import androidx.room.Query
import androidx.room.Transaction
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

@Dao
interface Dao {
    @Insert(entity = SongInstance::class)
    fun insertSongInHome(song: SongInstance)
    @Delete(entity = SongInstance::class)
    fun deleteSongFromHome(song: SongInstance)

    @Insert(entity = AddSongInstance::class)
    fun insertSongInBrowse(song: SongInstance)
    @Delete(entity = AddSongInstance::class)
    fun deleteSongFromBrowse(song: SongInstance)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM songs")
    fun getAllSong(): Flow<List<SongInstance>>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id = :id")
    fun getSongById(id: Int): Flow<SongInstance>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id > :id LIMIT 1")
    fun getNextSong(id: Int): Flow<SongInstance>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM songs WHERE id < :id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    fun getPreviousSong(id: Int): Flow<SongInstance>
    @Query("DELETE FROM songs")
    fun deleteAllSong()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM songs")
    fun getAllSongInBrowse(): Flow<List<SongInstance>>
}

I tried not to use database queries and everything worked right away, so the problem is in the db...

After adding or altering a table, you need to implement migration from your previous database version. (Otherwise you need to reinstall the app)
See documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions
Alternatively, you can use fallbackToDestructiveMigration() to always reset(clear) your DB after a sturctural change.

Unfortunately, fallbackToDestructiveMigration() didn't help.

If you're working on an unreleased app (so you are developing the first version) you can erase the app data from Android Settings (holding down the finger on app icon and entering in the app settings -> Storage), on the next start up this error will disappear.
But if you have to update an old app you released you need to migrate your database when you change the structure (add table, remove table, modify table, ecc...).
You have to raise up the database version number and add a MIGRATION query.
This is an example from one of my old apps, there are other ways, if you want to analyze it.
Some usefull documentation:
Android Documentation
Medium Guide
@Database(
version = DB_VERSION,
entities = [ParametriTable::class,
            UserTable::class],
    exportSchema = false )
abstract class JuniorDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

abstract fun mParametriDao() : ParametriDao
abstract fun mUsersDao() : UserDao

companion object {
    //Per migrare sostituire O con la vecchia versione e N con la nuovaù
    //                                     -->Versione vecchia
    //                                     |  -->Verrsione nuova
    //                                     |  |
    val MIGRATION_O_N = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE `Fruit` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "PRIMARY KEY(`id`))"
            )
        }
    }

    @Volatile
    private var instance: JuniorDatabase? = null
    fun getInstance(context: Context): JuniorDatabase {
        var oldVersion = JuniorShredPreferences.getDBversion(context)

        if(oldVersion != DB_VERSION){
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabaseWithMigration(context, oldVersion).also { instance = it }
            }
        }
        else {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): JuniorDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, JuniorDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME).build()
    }

    private fun buildDatabaseWithMigration(context: Context, oldVersion:Int?): JuniorDatabase {
        var oldDbVersion = oldVersion
        val newDb =  Room.databaseBuilder(context, JuniorDatabase::class.java, DB_NAME)
        when(oldDbVersion){
            1 ->{
                newDb.addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            }
        }
        return newDb.build()
    }

    val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            database.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE " +
                        "`nomi_file` (" +
                        "`fil_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fil_nome` TEXT, " +
                        "`fil_estensione` TEXT, " +
                        "`fil_nome_visualizzato` TEXT, " +
                        "`fil_mimetype` TEXT, " +
                        "`fil_dataora_upload` TEXT, " +
                        "`fil_valido_fino_al` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fil_note` TEXT, " +
                        "`fld_dataora_visto_prima` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fld_dataora_risposta` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`ute_nome` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fil_tipo` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fld_risposta` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`fil_nome_url` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`file_tipo` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "`file_risposta` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        "PRIMARY KEY(`fil_id`))"
            )
        }
    }
}

}
Or you can do as indicated by @Berťák with fallbackToDestructiveMigration()

To be honest, I don't quite understand how to clear the app data, could you explain it again?

You have to do it from your smartphone. Is literally the same process to clear data from an app like instagram or Facebook. You have to clear the app data from the phone. https://youtu.be/aQy-a8LOg4E?si=UQqVmkK76mGwRpmk
